# Converting Image URL to base64 - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to embed some images into a PDF using pdfmake. To do this, I need to use dataURIs for the images.

```
this.getDataUri = (url) => {
  var defer = $q.defer();

  var image = new Image();
  image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
  image.src = url;

  image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    defer.resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
  };

  image.onerror = function() {
    defer.reject();
  };

  return defer.promise;
}
```

I have this function to convert an image url into what I need, and this was working fine until recently, now I'm getting this error:

`Image from origin 'https://bucketeer-....s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here's my CORS settings for my S3 bucket:

```
{
  "CORSRules": [
    {
      "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
      ],
      "AllowedMethods": [
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST"
      ],
      "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: you need to add a cors policy on s3 bucket .... `<AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: @m0ngr31 How did you solve this? I'm running into the same issue trying to put images in a PDF

Answer (score 0):

same with me, when trying convert image url from s3 amazonaws to base 64. i get cors error

try like this

```
function getBase64FromImage(url, onSuccess, onError) {
    var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
    url = proxyUrl + url 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.open("GET", url);
 
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var base64, binary, bytes, mediaType;
 
        bytes = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
        //NOTE String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ...
        //may cause "Maximum call stack size exceeded"
        binary = [].map.call(bytes, function (byte) {
            return String.fromCharCode(byte);
        }).join('');
        mediaType = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
        base64 = [
            'data:',
            mediaType ? mediaType + ';':'',
            'base64,',
            btoa(binary)
        ].join('');
        onSuccess(base64);
    };
    xhr.onerror = onError;
    xhr.send();
}
```