# Use server to download image and serve to frontend

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-s3

I'm running into a CORS issue trying to pull images from S3 ([Converting Image URL to base64 - CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116298/converting-image-url-to-base64-cors-issue)).

I'm just using the images for a few seconds while I am generating a PDF file. Is there a way that I can have Meteor download the image and serve for just a few seconds so that I can get around the CORS problem?

I can't have Meteor just serve the images all the time since there are a ton of them and they change for the different reports.

Comment: Why not solve your CORS problems?  If it's your bucket, you can control that.  You **can** have your Node.js app proxy the images and add the appropriate headers, but it'd be far better to solve the root problem.

Comment: I've tried. I have the `AllowedOrigins` option set, but randomly it will just fail on some images (but work for others in the same batch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around the CORS issue by doing this:

```
import { request } from "meteor/froatsnook:request";

Meteor.methods({
    convertImage: function(imageUrl) {
      try {
        var result = request.getSync(imageUrl, {encoding: null});
        return 'data:image/png;base64,' + new Buffer(result.body).toString('base64');
      } catch(e) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("cant-download", "Error: Can't download image.");
      }
    }
});
```